# JavaScript Form validation on multiple input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can you check on more input fields? In my sample I have 2 input fields, if they are empty the border should be red.

But only the first border is red. How can I check on multiple fields.

```
function ValidationCheck() {
    var test1 = document.forms["myForm"]["f1"].value;
    var test2 = document.forms["myForm"]["f2"].value;

    if (isEmptyOrSpaces(test1)) {
        document.getElementById('f1').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('f1').style.borderColor = "#ccc";
    }


    if (isEmptyOrSpaces(test2)) {
        document.getElementById('f2').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('f2').style.borderColor = "#ccc";
    }   
}

 <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return ValidationCheck()">
    <label for="l1">Label1 (*):</label>
    <input type="text" id="f1">

    <label for="l2">Label2 (*):</label>
    <input type="text" id="f2">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: `isEmptyOrSpaces` I am not seeing this function in above code?

Comment: Maybe just some conditional logic to tighten up the code a bit like (isEmptyOrSpaces(test1) || isEmptyOrSpaces(test2)) { document.getElementById('f1').style.borderColor = "red"; document.getElementById('f2').style.borderColor = "red";

Comment: @NishantDixit its just a function that checks if the field is empty or spaces

Comment: It's because you `return` in the first if statement and your function exits before the second check is done.

Comment: @skyline3000 true but I tried to declare a "var valid" and then "valid = false". At the end this "if (valid) return true else false"

Comment: @user7998549 check my answer below, you can simply initialize the variable as true, switch it if the validation fails, and just return the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` after checking both validation

Try with this :)

```
function ValidationCheck() {
    var test1 = document.forms["myForm"]["f1"].value;
    var test2 = document.forms["myForm"]["f2"].value;
    var validationOk = true;
    if (isEmptyOrSpaces(test1)) {
        document.getElementById('f1').style.borderColor = "red";
        validationOk =  false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('f1').style.borderColor = "#ccc";
    }


    if (isEmptyOrSpaces(test2)) {
        document.getElementById('f2').style.borderColor = "red";
        validationOk = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('f2').style.borderColor = "#ccc";
    }
    if (!validationOk)
        return false;
}
```

Comment: This returns `false` when the validation is not okay but `undefined` otherwise... not sure that's desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Does this only need to be using JS? You can accomplish it with css pretty easily.

The issue is your returning false if the first field is empty and therefore it is stopping the rest of the code from executing. If you remove the return and place it outside at the end of the validationcheck it should work.